# Implementing Redux Devtools

Tags: reactjs, redux, devtools

I did the exact instructions in this post: https://medium.com/@samueldinesh/setting-up-redux-devtools-a-simple-guide-3b386a6254fa

The error I got was:
[image]

This is my code:

```
import {StrictMode} from 'react'
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import App from './App'
import './styles/globals.css'
import { store } from './store/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const rootElement = document.querySelector('#main')
const root = createRoot(rootElement)

const currentStore = createStore(
  store,
  composeWithDevTools()
)

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={currentStore}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please also note that you are probably writing a very outdated style of Redux here - modern Redux sets up the devtools for you automatically (since 2019). It also does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPEs or immutable reducer logic. Please read [Why Redux Toolkit is How To Use Redux Today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a store here. you should be passing rootReducer

```
const currentStore = createStore(
  store,
  composeWithDevTools()
)
```

// according to the link

```
const currentStore = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools()
)
```